# What's a good Perl code navigator?

Tags: perl

I'm about to write some plugins for a quite huge Perl project. Now I wanted to get a feeling for the project by reading interesting sections of the code. But I'm missing a good code navigator. Some of the features I'd like to see:

- right click on a sub call and navigate to the sub
- find all places where a sub is called
- find all places where a variable is used

Is there anything out there that does this for free?

EDIT: Also I'd like a navigate forward/back feature so that after a jump to a sub I can pick up where I left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the combination of these tools

- vim
- [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
- [taglist.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)

Comment: ctags sounds interesting, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: It seems that ctags only offers the possibility to jump to a declaration but not find all usages of a variable/sub. cscope sounds like it would be able to do what I'm looking for but I'm not sure yet if it really works with Perl.

Answer (score 5):

You can check either:

1. [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/), specifically aimed at refactoring;
2. [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)

check also the discussion [What's the best Perl IDE?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=639314).

If you don't like them, there is emacs...

Comment: Padre only seems capable to go to method declarations and only within a single file. I can't even navigate to a module declaration. Regarding Komodo Edit: Correct me if I'm wrong but their homepage states that code navigation is a feature of their non-free Komodo IDE.